# How to avoid a component rerendering after redux state changes?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a notification-popup system implemented with react and redux, every time I want to send a popup with a message I call a redux action that will change the state of a reducer and depending of the reducer's state I show a snackbar that is in a router-component wrapping child 'router' components, this is working very fine but I have a user experience problem because everytime this notification is showing up it is rerendering a navbar component that contains an image and you can see the image rerendering when the notification comes up.

This is weird to me because the notification action is not changing the state of the navbar that contains the image so I believe that it shouldn't be rerendering since it's not changing its state. Can someone give me a tip of what to do?

I was using getState() inside the redux thunks but I changed it so it's not used anymore since I found that it shouldn't be used: https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/idiomatic-redux-thoughts-on-thunks-sagas-abstraction-and-reusability/

And I rewrote the shouldComponentUpdate() function inside the navbar to verify that the props are different than nextProps so it doesnt rerender with that change but no luck yet! Thanks for any help.

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({
  isAuthenticated,
  component: Component,
  userColors,
  messages,
  ...rest
}) => (
    <Route {...rest} component={(props) => (
      isAuthenticated ? (
        <div className="private-route" style={{
          backgroundColor: userColors.bkg ? userColors.bkg : 'linear-gradient(#3366CB, #204080)'
        }}>
          <NavComponent />

// The snackbar is open when messages.showing is true (this comes from redux store)

          <SimpleSnackbar message={messages.currentMessage} open={messages.showing}/>
          <Component {...props} />
        </div>
      ) : (
          <Redirect to="/" />
        )
    )} />
  );
```

I can notify with actions so messages.showing becomes true and the snackbar is shown with

```
this.props.notify(error);
```

after that the snackbar is shown but it's rerendering the navbar component that is not using this state and has nothing to do with the reducer that is showing the snackbar producing that the image in navbar rerenders and doesnt feel all natural for the user.

The actions for the pop up are this:

```
export const notify = (message) => ({
    type: 'NOTIFY',
    message
});

export const close = () => ({
    type: 'CLOSE'
});
```

The reducer:

```
const messagesDefaultState = {
    currentMessage: '',
    showing: false
};

export default (state = messagesDefaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'NOTIFY':
        return {
            currentMessage: action.message,
            showing: true
        };
      case 'CLOSE':
        return messagesDefaultState;
      default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

and there's a navbar component that connect to redux store and contains an avatar that is flickering everytime I call notify from the actions.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Avatar from 'react-avatar';
    import { startLogout } from '../actions/auth';
    import { startSetIdiom, startSetIdioms } from '../actions/idiom';

    export class NavComponent extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        };

        shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
            const differentPP = this.props.pp !== nextProps.pp;
            const differentName = this.props.name !== nextProps.name;
            return differentPP || differentName;
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            if(this.props.idiomData === ''){
                this.props.startSetIdioms();
                this.props.startSetIdiom('EN');
            }
        };

        burgerToggle = () => {
            let linksEl = document.querySelector('.narrowLinks');
            if (linksEl.style.display === 'block') {
                linksEl.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                linksEl.style.display = 'block';
            }
        };

        render() {
            return (
                <nav>
                    <div className="navWide">
                        <div className="wideDiv">
                            <Link className="header__link header__link_home" to="/dashboard">
                                <i className="fas fa-home header__icon"></i>
                            </Link>
                            <Link className="header__link header__link_title show-for-desktop" to="/dashboard">{this.props.idiomData.navTitle && this.props.idiomData.navTitle || 'Main Menu'} </Link>
                            <div className="header__end">
                                <Link to="/changeProfilePic">

//This avatar is flickering everytime I call notify or close from the snackbar actions

<Avatar size="34px" name={this.props.name} src={this.props.pp} round={true}/></Link>    
                                <Link  className="nav__link" to="/profilePic">{this.props.idiomData.greeting  && this.props.idiomData.greeting || 'Hello, '} {this.props.name && this.props.name || ''}</Link>
                                <button className="nav__link">{this.props.idiom}</button>
                                <button className="nav__link" onClick={this.props.startLogout}>{this.props.idiomData.logOut || 'Logout'}</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="navNarrow">
                        <Link className="header__link header__link_home" to="/dashboard">
                            <i className="fas fa-home header__icon"></i>
                        </Link>
                        <div onClick={this.burgerToggle}>
                            <i className="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                        </div>                  
                        <div className="narrowLinks">                   
                            <Link className="nav__link" to="/profilePic">{this.props.idiomData.greeting ? this.props.idiomData.greeting : 'Hello, ' } {this.props.name && this.props.name || ''}<Avatar size="34px" name={this.props.name} src={this.props.pp} round={true}/></Link>
                            <button className="nav__link">{this.props.idiom}</button>
                            <button className="nav__link" onClick={this.props.startLogout}>{this.props.idiomData.logOut || 'Logout'}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            );
        };
    };

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
        name: state.dash.userData.name,
        pp: state.dash.userData.profilePic,
        idiom: state.idiom.currentIdiom ? state.idiom.currentIdiom : 'EN',
        idiomData: state.idiom.idiomData.launchpad ? state.idiom.idiomData.launchpad : ''
    });

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
        startLogout: () => dispatch(startLogout()),
        startSetIdiom: (idiom) => dispatch(startSetIdiom(idiom)),
        startSetIdioms: () => dispatch(startSetIdioms())
    });

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavComponent);
```

Comment: Hi, I wrote that "Thunks" blog post. I think you may have missed the point. I was trying to say that it's _fine_ to use `getState()` in a thunk, not that you should stop doing so.  As for your actual question: can you clarify what you mean by "image is rerendering"?  Are you talking about a React component rendering, or the image is visibly flickering on screen?  Also, can you show how you're connecting the components to Redux, and what the reducer looks like?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mark and nice blog, as you say the image is visibly flickering on screen, I edited my question trying to bring more information thanks!

Comment: @Farid are you using Immutable.js for your state? Redux creates a new state object on every update, meaning every component that listens to that state will re-render unless you have some type of immutable object store or `shouldComponentUpdate` methods

Comment: Thank you Im not using Immutable but I am using the shouldComponentUpdate in the component that is re-rendering (NavComponent) as shown in the question, I wonder if it's not enough because it's still rerendering even though the props are not changin when I compare them (see NavComponent shouldComponentUpdate method) will try immutable now